# How to solve this problem with css card flip?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am creating register form for my new django project. I am trying to make a form such that it displays the register form, but when someone hovers over it, it will display the login form.
[image]

> > Q) Why are the two button from the '***front'*** class being displayed here ?
> > Q) And I tried using flex box to center things in the 'login' form but it didn't work, why it is not working?

```css
/* `-> CREATE ACCOUNT HEADING ENDs*/


/* `-> REGISTER FORM */

.my-register-card {
  width: 85vw;
  height: 383px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10vw;
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: slideInFromBottom .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.my-register-card:hover {
  /* transform: scale(1.02); */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .my-register-card {
    width: 380px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 871px) {
  .my-register-card {
    animation: slideInFromRight .7s ease-in-out;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  .my-register-card {
    margin-right: 0vw;
  }
}


/**/


/* THIS IS WHERE THAT FLIP ANIMATION COMES FROM */

.my-register-container {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  position: relative;
}

.my-register-container:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.my-register-form-field {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.my-register-form-field:last-child {
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-register-container label {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #494949;
}

.my-register-container input {
  all: unset;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  width: 85%;
  transition: .2s;
}

.front form .my-register-form-field:first-child input {
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input:focus {
  width: 92%;
  color: #242e4c;
}

.front form .my-register-form-field:first-child input:focus {
  width: 50%;
}

.my-register-container button {
  all: unset;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #242e4c;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: .2s;
}

.my-register-container button:hover {
  transform: scale(.95);
  cursor: pointer
}

.my-register-container .front button:first-child {
  width: 75%;
}

.my-register-container .front button:last-child {
  background-color: #218838;
  width: 20%;
}

.my-register-container .back button:first-child {
  background-color: #218838;
  width: 70%;
}

.my-register-container .back button:last-child {
  width: 25%;
}

.forgot-password {
  text-align: center;
}


/* `-> Register Form Animations */

@keyframes slideInFromRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes slideInFromTop {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-500%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes slideInFromBottom {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-register-card">
  <div class="my-register-container">
    <div class="front">
      <form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
        <div class="my-register-form-field">
          <label>Name</label><br>
          <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required autocomplete="off">
          <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="my-register-form-field">
          <label for="id_email">E-mail</label><br>
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email here." autocomplete="off" required="" id="id_email">
        </div>
        <div class="my-register-form-field">
          <label for="id_password1">Password</label><br>
          <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Set a password." autocomplete="off" required="" id="id_password1">
        </div>
        <div class="my-register-form-field">
          <label for="id_password2">Confirm Password</label><br>
          <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm your password." required="" id="id_password2">
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="ref" value="{{ request.GET.ref }}" maxlength="50" id="id_ref_id" hidden> {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="my-register-form-field">
          <button type="submit">Register</button>
          <button>Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <form class="login" method="POST" action="/accounts/login/">
        <div class="my-register-form-field">
          <label for="id_login">E-mail</label><br>
          <input type="email" name="login" placeholder="Enter your email here." autocomplete="email" required="" id="id_login">
        </div>
        <div class="my-register-form-field">
          <label for="id_password">Password</label><br>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" autocomplete="current-password" required="" id="id_password"></p>
        </div>
        <p class="forgot-password"><a href="/accounts/password/reset/">Forgot Password?</a></p>
        <div class="my-register-form-field">
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
          <button>Register</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To clarify, you want the flip animation to stay, just not show the opposite side content?

Comment: @Y.S. No, I just want to know why the register and login button from the 'front' class are being displayed when flipped

Comment: The `scale()` function in `.my-register-container button` seems to be causing the `front` class buttons to show up when card is flipped.